# Is it possible to use EclipseLink HistoryPolicy to track user activity?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, history, user-activity

I am using EclipseLink HistoryPolicy to track changes over entities and my entities have `CREATEDBY` and `UPDATEDBY` properties.

With the help of these properties and EclipseLink History Queries, can I get user's activity related to specific entity over time?

For example

```
-User1 created an employee with the id of 34 at 2016-04-22 13:53:44
-User2 updated an employee with the id of 34 at 2016-05-04 17:25:21
etc.
```

If not, how can I achieve this task in an efficient way?